# Find for a patten on change of HTML element and remove it using backbone or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, backbone.js

I update the Backbone Model with `...` if it is empty when the control gains focus.

```
code snippet : 
events :{
    "focusin input"     : "updateCell"
},
updateCell: function(event) {
    if(_.isEmpty(event.target.value)){
             var inputID = event.target.id;
             var value = "...";
             var attribute = {};
             attribute[inputID] = value;
             this.model.set(attribute);
             }
        }
```

This works fine and update the `model` if it is empty but `...` is appended with the value.

Instead I want to remove `...` when the user starts to enter the value and some cases the `focus` might have come to one control and the user could have skipped without entering anything. So I want to remove the `...` also when saving the data to server.

Please help me to solve these two problems. It is fine even if I have to go with

```
 jquery or underscore.js etc
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the value attribute for the default value, instead, use the placeholder attribute.
When the user will click on the field, the placeholder text in your case "..." will disappear automatically.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the post, I am not showing `...` on the control, it is shown on the header automatically when we add the value to a model.